# Compute the volume of the solid bounded by $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ and $y\geq1$.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Compute the volume of the solid bounded by $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ and $y\geq1$.

Setting the boundaries: $-\sqrt{3}\leq x\leq \sqrt{3}, 1\leq y\leq2, -\sqrt{3}\leq z\leq \sqrt{3}$

$\displaystyle 4\int_0^{\sqrt{3}}\int_1^2\int_0^{\sqrt{3}}\,dz\,dy\,dx=12$

Can someone check if this looks correct? Thank you.

Comment: As it stands, you are computing the volume of a rectangle.

Comment: This is a [spherical cap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap), with radius=2, and height=1. V=$5\pi/3$. You can derive the formula from the volume of a solid of revolution.

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct, because it allows the point $(\sqrt 3,2,\sqrt 3)$ which has $\sqrt 3^2+2^2+\sqrt 3^2=10$. You have to express the limits of the $x$ integral in terms of $y$ and the $z$ integral in terms of $x$ and $y$.

For example, as you say you have $1\leq y \leq 2$. Then if we use $x$, we have $x^2=4-y^2$ (since we're ignoring $z$ for the moment), so $-\sqrt{4-y^2}\leq x \leq \sqrt{4-y^2}$.